# How can I easily transfer videos from iPhone to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, imovie

iPhone records nicer videos than iPad, but working with iMovie on iPad is more pleasant than on iPhone. How can I easily transfer recorded videos from iPhone to iPad, preferably without using a computer?

There are many ways to share photos easily like Photo Stream and [direct device to device beaming](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/03/09/how-to-beam-your-photos-with-iphoto-for-ios/) using the iPhoto app, but these do not work (yet) for videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since PhotoStream doesn't work for videos, your best bet is probably a 3rd party app.

If you're worried about your pictures being stored on the Internet, you might want to try an app such as [PhotoSync](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2011/02/22/photosync-transfer-media-between-ios-devices-mac-and-pc/) ($2) or [Photo Transfer App](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57401774-285/easily-transfer-photos-and-videos-between-macs-and-ios-devices/) ($3). The former seems like it uses your Bluetooth or Wi-Fi connection to transfer between the two devices rather than uploading the pictures to a webserver and then downloading them on the other device.

I believe that any 3rd party app that deals with photos will need to be granted access to location information. The app isn't necessarily using the location information, it's just that that information is embedded inside of pictures taken while location services was enabled. Therefore, since the app *could* potentially access your location info, it needs privileges to do so, even if it never ends up actually doing so.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand why it might need to access location information from the photos. But: 1) my photos and videos don't include location, since I have that disabled. 2) even after I've enabled it to use location information, it has then asked me for my current location. 3) When I turned off location services during upload process, upload was aborted. I don't want to keep location services enabled during entire upload, especially when uploading big videos :-(

Comment: When I say "it" in my above comment, I refer to Dropbox. I will try the other apps you've mentioned.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný: Your best bet might be iPhoto as [Michal mentioned](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45151/218) since it's only a bit more expensive and it's by Apple. Additionally, it does other things as well besides just sending photos/videos.

Comment: unfortunately beaming in iPhoto doesn't work for videos :-(

Comment: I highly recommend PhotoSync.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not use [iCloud](http://www.icloud.com) and would like access on a PC or a web browser then you can use **[DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/)**, this free app (sign up required) will allow you to save photos and videos to a folder in the cloud. You can access this folder on both iPhone, iPad and also your computer.

You also have to give Dropbox permission to access your photos from the iPhone app

1. In the app go to Uploads, (on the bottom)
2. Click the + button
3. Allow access to your photos
4. tap on the videos you wish to put onto your iPad
5. choose a folder to upload them into(you can create new folders here too.
6. Choose the folder and upload.
7. Wait a short time and navigate to the file using DropBox on the iPad. you can then save the video tyo your videos and open in iMovie.

[image]

The benefit of this over using iCloud is that you are instantly starting the process, iCloud and photostream can take a few minutes to start the sync process, you also have th eoption to be able to open the videos on a web browser, which you cannot do on iCloud.com

Comment: Do you suggest using Photo Stream? That doesn't work for videos :-( But using DropBox sounds good, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, DropBox says that it needs location access to upload my videos (?!?). That's a deal-breaker.

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný: See [my answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45150/218) for an explanation as to why it might be asking for location access.

Answer (score 0):

Just email them to yourself. You may have to trim some of the video but it's simple and works.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Apple's iPhoto for iOS you can "beam" photos and movies between devices.

Some tutorials:

- [How-to: Beam your photos with iPhoto for iOS @ TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/03/09/how-to-beam-your-photos-with-iphoto-for-ios/)
- [How to set up and use iPhoto Beam on iOS @ cnet](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57393546-285/how-to-set-up-and-use-iphoto-beam-on-ios/)

They describe how to do it with photos but movies should work as well.

Comment: Actually videos don't work. When you select video and try to beam it, it says "Selected (0)" on the "Beam" page. It works fine for photos though.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for checking though. I have only one iOS device so couldn't check the whole process.

Comment: This is a great answer - can anyone find a question that asks about beaming photos so we can find this answer a better home?

Comment: @MichalM Ah, beaming! Take me back to the days of PalmOS back 1998...