# How can I wirelessly get videos off of a new iPad?

Tags: data-synchronization, video, ipad, photo-stream

If one has a New iPad and uses it to shoot video, is there a way to wirelessly transfer videos off the iPad and onto my Mac?

We've established that [PhotoStream is for still photos only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45341/does-photostream-copy-videos-too-or-just-still-photos), so that won't be the solution.

Comment: Here's a related question about [transferring videos from iPhone to iPad](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/45138/218).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [iTunes Wi-Fi syncing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386).

Prior to iOS 5, you would have to plug in your device to sync with iTunes.

As of iOS 5, 2 new features were introduced:

- iCloud
- Wi-Fi syncing with iTunes

For people like me that mainly used iTunes for backup purposes, iCloud eliminated the need for syncing with iTunes altogether. However, there are people that still sync with iTunes and thus Wi-Fi syncing could help.

It does the exact same thing as syncing with the cable but you don't need to have anything attached. Both computers just need to be on the same Wi-Fi network. Apple has all the steps necessary in order to get this working.

One of the things lacking on Apple's page is how to force a sync from your device. On an iPhone, you would do the following:

1. Launch **Settings**.
2. Navigate to **General > iTunes Wi-Fi Sync**
3. Press **Sync Now**. (Note: This will only appear if you have set up Wi-Fi syncing according to Apple's directions and that computer is on and connected to the same network.)

Comment: Hmm I haven't tried it (since I don't sync to a computer), but it's possible that Photos includes videos. The 1st image on that site under USB sync shows the Photos tab on top, and I'm pretty sure it has video settings there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a 3rd party app such as [PhotoSync](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2011/02/22/photosync-transfer-media-between-ios-devices-mac-and-pc/) ($2).

The advantages are:

- It won't degrade the quality (unlike email).
- It doesn't require you to sync the entire device (unlike iTunes Wi-Fi sync).
- It doesn't send the data over the Internet (unlike an app such as Dropbox).

Answer (score 0):

When you open a video in your photo library you have the option to email video, send to YouTube.

You can also copy it in case some third party app lets you paste a video for upload? Dropbox (for iPad) can upload videos too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are looking for some kind of synchronization solution (e.g., an app to push your personal videos), the simplest solution would be to email it to yourself via the built in sharing feature.